# Mapbox free billing period

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, maps

I am trying to use mapbox instead of leaflet to allow client to modify in the map if needed because I found in mapbox studio a friendly interface for modifying the map .

Is the free period in mapbox limited only for a month or is forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's free but you will have "only"
50,000 map views / mo, or
50,000 mobile users / mo

More infos here:
https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/#

Comment: Keep in mind that 50,000 map views in not the same as 50,000 page views. I've found that it works out to about 2-4 mapviews per page view, depending on how much surfing is done: https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-map-view/